# How to hide number pad using background Tap?

Tags: ios, xcode, numpad

I study iOS SDK using [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X) and in 4 Chapter, when it tells you how to hide number pad with background tap I have a problem. I do that author says but nothing happened. How I can do this?
 What book's author says:

1)Create new method backgroundTap in ViewController.h

```
- (IBAction)touchBackground:(id)sender;
```

2)Add method in ViewController.m

```
-(void)touchBackground:(id)sender{
[nameField resignFirstResponder];
[numberField resignFirstResponder];}
```

3)Change class identity of View object in Interface Builder(as I understand in Xcode 4 its Control) from UIView to UIControl

4)Connect TouchDown method in events list with File's Owner and check method backgroundTap.

This is my code samples

- [ViewController.h](http://www.sourcepod.com/fxdizz09-6312)
- [ViewController.m](http://www.sourcepod.com/mrsdkk75-6313)

P.S. I'm sorry for my English, I translated all information from the book to english because I have russian translate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might make this simpler by just implementing a method like this:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

make the background view `UIControl` instead of `UIView` in interface builder and hook the touches up event to this method.

Have a look at this [small example project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/DelegationExample.zip). I have done exactly  this in the `secondViewController` where touching the background dismissed the keyboard. You can also see how I have changed the background to a `UIControl` in `secondViewController.xib`

Answer (score 3):

Something you might want to try, without changing the background view, is:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [nameField resignFirstResponder];
    [numberField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have done Step 4 ("Connect TouchDown method in events list with File's Owner and check method backgroundTap") incorrectly. Include an NSLog in your touchBackground method to check whether the method is being called.

```
-(void)touchBackground:(id)sender{
[nameField resignFirstResponder];
[numberField resignFirstResponder];
NSLog(@"touchBackground was called");
}
```

If the message ("touchBackground was called") doesn't show up in your console, then you known touchBackground is not being called.